# WSO2 API Manager installation : Apt install unable to locate package wso2am-3.2.0

Tags: wso2, debian, wso2-api-manager, apt, api-manager

I used WSO2 in the past, v2.6.0. I installed it through their debian repository on a Debian 9 machine, and it worked well.

Now I want to install their new 3.2.0 stable version on a Debian 9 machine, so I followed their guidelines here : https://wso2.com/api-management/install/apt/get-started/

Unfortunately, the apt install command fails and I don't understand why :

```
apt update && apt install wso2am-3.2.0
```

> Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
>
> Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
>
> Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
>
> Ign:4 https://dl.bintray.com/wso2/deb am_320 InRelease
>
> Get:5 https://dl.bintray.com/wso2/deb am_320 Release [1,897 B]
>
> Hit:5 https://dl.bintray.com/wso2/deb am_320 Release
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> All packages are up to date.
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package wso2am-3.2.0
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'wso2am-3.2.0'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wso2am-3.2.0'

Here is my Debian version :

```
lsb_release -a
```

> Distributor ID:   Debian
>
> Description:  Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
>
> Release:  9.13
>
> Codename: stretch

And my /etc/apt/sources.list file :

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

> deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
>
> deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
>
> deb https://dl.bintray.com/wso2/deb am_320 release

I tried with http only, but I got the same error. Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try again these steps?

```
apt-get update
apt-get install wso2am-3.2.0
```

Now it will work since we fixed some problems with the installer and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I see... I seems this file https://dl.bintray.com/wso2/deb/pool/w/wso2am-3.2.0/wso2am-linux-installer-x64-3.2.0.deb was missing in your repository. Thank you for you quick fix!